# How to Get content External link to div from Listview Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[question]: I can't get content external link to **div=contentlink** form listview Jquery. This code is below: ( or check at: http://jsfiddle.net/z36UK/2/ )

```
<div id="wrap">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." id="ds-canho">
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $.mobile.loading( "show" );
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http://saigonpearl.info/home/notype/-0-trang-chu.html%27%20and%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%27tindang%27%5D%22&diagnostics=true',
      dataType: "xml",
      success: parseXml
    });

    function parseXml(xml) {
      $(xml).find("div.tindang").each(function() {
        var url = $(this).find('a').attr("href"),
            urlx= url.replace('#menutop','');

        //find each instance of loc in xml file and wrap it in a link
        $("ul#ds-canho").append('<li><a href='+ urlx +'>' + $(this).find('h3').text() + '</a></li>');
        $('ul#ds-canho').listview('refresh');
        console.log( this );
        $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
      });
    }
  });



</script></body>
```

Comment: `$(xml).find("div.tindang")...` which divs have the class `tindang`??

Comment: File XML is format: <div class="tindang"><h3> Content1 </h3> </div> <div class="tindang"><h3> Content2 </h3> </div>..... You can check my url XML file

Comment: the last line of your code: `$("$my-content").load(urlx);` is wrong. what is `my-content`? an id or class. it has to be `$("#my-content").load(urlx);` if it is an id.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/z36UK/1/

Comment: yep, '$("$my-content").load(urlx);' can remove so it doesnt affect code.

Comment: How to Get content External link from listview to div page ?